# Install fonts to Quickoffice?

Tags: google, fonts, quickoffice

I'm looking to get the standard Word fonts on QuickOffice for Android. Is it possible? All my searches on the internet have yielded nothing.

If it isn't possible, are the fonts that QuickOffice does have identical to any of the standards?

I mainly just need Helvetica, Arial, and Times New Roman. (Required for some classes.)

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575) / [Does Android support new fonts?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/48639/16575) / [How to install full Unicode fonts](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41227/16575) / [Microsoft “web safe” fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9736/16575)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative may be to use the OfficeSuite app instead. It has a PAID partner font app (OfficeSuite Font Package) which includes Arial and Times New Roman; sadly, no Helvetica.